# How can I implement DDD Aggregates without dependency on the persistence layer

Tags: entity-framework-core

When implementing DDD aggregates I usually have them expose methods that represent business functions and then those functions are responsible for modifying internal state. E.g.

```
public class Order
{
     public int Id { get; private set; }
     public IEnumerable<LineItem> LineItems { get; private set; }

     public void AddLineItem(...) {...}
     public void Ship() {...}
     public void Cancel() {...}
}
```

When using EF6 or NHibernate this works well because the context/session can detect all insertions/deletes/updates of child entities. However, with EF7 I need to explicitly instruct the change tracker about such changes. E.g. when `AddLineItem()` adds a new line item to the LineItems collection, we must either manually add it to a `DBSet` on the context or inform the change tracker that the state for that line item was `Added`.

This means my domain objects must have an explicit dependency on Entity Framework and I must now somehow pass around references to the context (or change tracker) when calling business functions.

Is this something I should simply work around for the moment, on the basis that EF7 will ultimately have the same capabilities as EF6/NHibernate? Or is there a way to have rich domain objects without this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using dependency injection. This would allow separation of your domain objects from your ORM of choice (plus all the other benefits of dependency injection). There is no single, absolutely correct answer for how exactly you separate concerns in your code.

*Related note:* the behavior of `.Add()` will be changing in EF7 - beta 8 (See [PR#2979](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/2979)). The change tracker will now include all "children" entities when you call .Add for a parent item.

Comment: Thanks @natemcmaster. I'm a big fan of dependency injection but not so much with the domain objects themselves - simply because when working with an ORM there is often little control over the materialisation of the objects from the persistence store. 
I see they are proposing changes to support propagation to child objects, but it still seems unclear whether this will apply to all operations (Add, Update, Delete).

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt the change will apply to Add/Attach/Update. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(August-27,-2015)#addattach-for-graphs for even more details. Delete is still under review.